# How do I strike through an entire row in a prawn PDF table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pdf-generation, prawn

I have a Prawn PDF that prints off a list of tickets in a table:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("doorlist.pdf") do
  table([["Ticket", "Name", "Product"]] + tickets.map do |ticket|
    [
     make_cell(:content => ticket.number, :font => "Courier"),
     make_cell(:content => ticket.holder.full_name),
     make_cell(:content => ticket.product.name)
    ]
  end, :header => true)
end
```

And I'd like to strike through the rows where ticket.has_been_used? is true. I can see in the Prawn documentation http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf that I can strike through each cell's text with the :inline_format option to Document.generate and wrapping the text in `"<strikethrough>#{text}</strikethrough>"` but is it possible to strike through the whole line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go at this, and this is what I ended up with:

The strategy was to create a new table for each row, and specify fixed widths for the columns so the vertical separators line up. After drawing a table (row), I check my conditional, and if true, I move the cursor up half the height of a cell, draw my line, then move it back down to where it was.

```
require 'prawn'
tickets = [
  {:number => '123', :name => 'John', :product => 'Foo', :used => true },
  {:number => '124', :name => 'Bill', :product => 'Bar', :used => false},
  {:number => '125', :name => 'John', :product => 'Baz', :used => true}
]

Prawn::Document.generate("doorlist.pdf") do

  widths = [150,180,200]
  cell_height = 20

  table([["Ticket", "Name", "Product"]], :column_widths => widths)

  tickets.each do |ticket|

    table([[
      make_cell(:content => ticket[:number],  :height => cell_height, :font => "Courier"),
      make_cell(:content => ticket[:name],    :height => cell_height, :font => "Courier"),
      make_cell(:content => ticket[:product], :height => cell_height, :font => "Courier")
    ]], :column_widths => widths)

    if ticket[:used]
      move_up (cell_height/2)
      stroke_horizontal_rule
      move_down (cell_height/2)
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Hey, that looks pretty good! It'd be nice in general not to have fixed column widths but for what I'm doing it's fine.

Comment: @synecdoche You could probably just write your table out, and be sure to use the fixed *height* cells, and just absolutely move the cursor to the right position, and loop over the data a second time with each_with_index and use the index to calculate how far down to move the cursor, but I didn't want to make too many assumptions about what would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
idx = 0 

        tableTest = pdf.make_table(data)


        while idx <= totalRows
            if tableTest.cells[idx, 2].content == "No Go"
                tableTest.cells[idx, 2].style(:background_color => 'FF0000')
            else 
                tableTest.cells[idx, 2].style(:background_color => '00FF22')
            end 
            idx += 1 
        end 

        tableTest.draw

        pdf.render_file "example.pdf"
```

This works. You need to just make the table then iterate and change the individual cells later.